# PHP Preg Replace - Match String with Space - Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to scan my wordpress content for:

```
<p><span class="embed-youtube">some iframed video</span></p>
```

and then change it into:

```
<p class="img_wrap"><span class="embed-youtube">some iframed video</span></p>
```

using the following code in my function.php file in my theme:

```
$classes = 'class="img_wrap"';
$youtube_match = preg_match('/(<p.*?)(.*?><span class="embed-youtube")/', $content, $youtube_array);

if(!empty($youtube_match))
 {
  $content = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)(.*?><span class=\"embed-youtube\")/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $content);
 }
```

but for some reason I am not getting a match on my regex nor is the replace working.  I don't understand why there isn't a match because the span with class embed-youtube exists.

UPDATE - HERE IS THE FULL FUNCTION

```
function give_attachments_class($content){
   $classes = 'class="img_wrap"';
   $img_match = preg_match("/(<p.*?)(.*?><img)/", $content, $img_array);
   $youtube_match = preg_match('/(<p.*?)(.*?><span class="embed-youtube")/', $content, $youtube_array);

   // $doc = new DOMDocument;
   // @$doc->loadHTML($content); // load the HTML data

   // $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
   // $nodes = $xpath->query('//p/span[@class="embed-youtube"]');

   // foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   //    $node->parentNode->setAttribute('class', 'img_wrap');
   // }

   // $content = $doc->saveHTML();


   if(!empty($img_match))
    {
     $content = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)(.*?><img)/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $content);
    }
   else if(!empty($youtube_match))
    {
     $content = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)(.*?><span class=\"embed-youtube\")/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $content);
    }

   $content = preg_replace("/<img(.*?)src=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)(|\")(.*?)>/", '<img$1 data-original=$3.$4 $6>' , $content);

   return $content;
  }
```

add_filter('the_content','give_attachments_class');

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using regex, make effective use of [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and **XPath** to do this for you.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//p/span[@class="embed-youtube"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   $node->parentNode->setAttribute('class', 'img_wrap');
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly work with wordpress.  I'm using the_content() in wordpress and I don't want to full have a new document with a doctype etc.  I just want to transform the html output from the_content()

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty REGEX I did for you.  It finds the entire string starting with p tag, ending p tag, span also included etc.  I also wrote it to include single or double quotes for you since you never know and also to include spaces in various places.  Let me know how it works out for you, thanks.

```
(<p )+(class=)['"]+img_wrap+['"](><span)+[ ]+(class=)+['"]embed-youtube+['"]>[A-Za-z0-9='" ]+(</span></p>)
```

I have tested it on your code and a few other variations and it works for me.

Comment: How does this regex fit in preg_match and preg_replace?  I tried adding it but I seem to be getting a lot of syntax issues with the ' and "

Comment: It works when you test on this site. http://regexr.com/  Check your code, my regex works just fine.

Comment: Why more than 1 single/double quote, `['"]+`? Why `[ ]+`? Where is the OP suppose to use this? @JasonBiondo did @hwnd's answer not work for you, do you require regex for some reason?

Comment: @chris85 - see my comment regarding wordpress.